# Como posso consultar última procedure deletada do banco de dados

Tags: sql, sql-server

É possível consultar qual foi a última procedure deletada no banco de dados?
Se sim, como posso fazer isso?

O objetivo é conseguir recriá-la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom consegui salvar o que foi deletado em 2 passos.

A solução veio de uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796916/how-to-retrieve-dropped-stored-procedure-function-table-in-sql-server-2008/27813771#27813771) do `SO` em inglês que o [Randrade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/20615/randrade) me mostrou, vou compartilhar aqui pois pode salvar a pele de outra pessoa ^^.

```
 1. Passo:

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Recover_Dropped_Objects]
        @Database_Name NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Date_From DATETIME,
        @Date_To DATETIME
    AS

    DECLARE @Compatibility_Level INT

    SELECT @Compatibility_Level=dtb.compatibility_level
    FROM master.sys.databases AS dtb WHERE dtb.name=@Database_Name

    IF ISNULL(@Compatibility_Level,0)<=80
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('The compatibility level should be equal to or greater SQL SERVER 2005 (90)',16,1)
        RETURN
    END

    Select [Database Name],Convert(varchar(Max),Substring([RowLog Contents 0],33,LEN([RowLog Contents 0]))) as [Script]
    from fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
    Where [Operation]='LOP_DELETE_ROWS' And [Context]='LCX_MARK_AS_GHOST'
    And [AllocUnitName]='sys.sysobjvalues.clst'
    AND [TRANSACTION ID] IN (SELECT DISTINCT [TRANSACTION ID] FROM    sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
    WHERE Context IN ('LCX_NULL') AND Operation in ('LOP_BEGIN_XACT') 
    And [Transaction Name]='DROPOBJ'
    And  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(11),[Begin Time]) BETWEEN @Date_From AND @Date_To)
    And Substring([RowLog Contents 0],33,LEN([RowLog Contents 0]))<>0

 2. Passo:
EXEC sp_Recover_Dropped_Objects 'Database_Name','2017/10/06','2017/10/06'
```

Answer (score -1):

Sim, é possível.

Com o `SELECT` abaixo, dado de exemplo, você consegue obter todos logs relacionados aos DROP's da sua base, como início da consulta, o tipo da operação e outros IDs de transação, todos eles obtidos pela função `fn_dblog`.

```
SELECT 
Operation,
[Transaction Id],
[Transaction SID],
[Transaction Name],
 [Begin Time],
   [SPID],
   Description
FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
WHERE [Transaction Name] = 'DROPOBJ'
```

Para descobrir o usuário, basta pegar o valor da coluna Transaction SID (obtida no SELECT acima) e passa-lo na função `SUSER_SNAME()`, que retorna o nome do usuário que realizou o DROP.

Ex:

```
SELECT SUSER_SNAME(VALOR_TRANSACTION_SID)
```

Comment: Consegui visualizar os logs mas não sei como usá-los para encontrar o nome da procedure, existe uma função similar a suser_sname para proc?